# Failed to load eslint library in V8

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I can get eslint to work in my projects if I run:

`npm i -D eslint@7.32.0`

However, all of the newest versions of frameworks don't support this version. Angular and Sveltekit, for example, now use the latest version 8.

I am using Windows 11 with Powershell. All of my projects give the same error.

In both my local `.vsocde/settings.json` and global `settings.json` file I have this:

```json
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "eslint.runtime": "",
    "eslint.validate": [
        "vue",
        "html",
        "javascript",
        "typescript",
        "javascriptreact",
        "typescriptreact"
    ],
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true,
    },
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        {
            "mode": "auto"
        }
    ],
    "eslint.useESLintClass": true,
    "eslint.nodePath": "C:\\Users\\jdgam\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules"
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled eslint gloabally `npm i -g eslint`.

No matter what I do, I still get this error even on a brand new clean project.

I have ESLint VS Code Extension v2.2.6 (latest).

[image: eslint error]

How can I get version 8 working on my Windows machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out some of my VS Code plugin extensions were causing the issue. I basically uninstalled all of them, and reinstalled only the necessary ones. I was not able to figure out which one at this time, but probably a pretty print extension.

J